# Embed non-related task list into Power Apps as a sub form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp

I am trying to set up a Power app for my company to help keep track of the trip planning process. The tasks are the same for every trip being planned.

Lists:

- TaskList - (Name, Category, Attachments)
- TripList- (Trip Name, cost, location, dates, overall task progress)

Power app Items:

- Trip List Form - Connected to TripList
- TaskGallery - Connected to TaskList including a Status combobox with a table ({Text:"Ongoing",Val:0.5},{Text: "Complete",Val:1}...)

What I need is a way to View,Edit, and update the TaskGallery status for each Trip name.

I tried a Collection with the Trip Name and a nested Task List Table (Task Name and Status Combo Box), but it is reset on every refresh. I tried saving it separately to a Third SharePoint, but the nested table does not save. I feel like I am so close, but stuck on a final step.

In InfoPath and Access, I was able to use a subform, but Power Apps does not have this direct function..

I am stuck trying to save the Information from the gallery to my SharePoint.